# В ЛинуксМинт есть опция "Запись образа на USB-носитель". Это простая копия системы или создание загрузочного диска с флешки?

Tags: запись

В ЛинуксМинт есть опция "Запись образа на USB-носитель". Это простая копия системы или создание загрузочного диска с флешки?

Comment: Если образ загрузочный, это создаст загрузочную флешку.

Answer (score 0):

Это запись любого iso-образа.
Подробнее [тут](https://info-comp.ru/drugieopersistemi/659-burn-iso-to-usb-in-linux-mint.html)